# Sound and Badge not working in Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've linked my Swift Storyboard project with Firebase push notifications.
The notifications are currently arriving, but the problem is that the notifications are coming without sound or badge to display.

If I check the notification.request.content.sound or notification.request.content.badge... is displaying nil...

Anyone has face this? Do I missing something in the code to recieve the notification with the sound and badge?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var fcmTokenPreviafy: String = ""
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }

}
```

And here are the extensions:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate{
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)
        return [[ .alert, .badge, .sound ]]
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print(userInfo)
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
        
        print(userInfo)
        return UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
    }
    
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate{
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        
      let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
      )
        fcmTokenPreviafy = fcmToken!
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sound and badging require the appropriate payload to be sent in your FCM message. What payload are you sending?

Comment: @Paulw11 I’ve read about that, but I dont know how to edit or set the payload in the code… didnt find any answer to show me how to do it…

Comment: Or do I need to edit the push notification payload from the backend and add the “sound:default”?

Comment: Yes, the payload is what your backend sends. You need to specify `sound:default` for iOS.   You also need to specify the `badge` value if you want to badge the app icon with a number - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification